# vim how to paste multiple lines insert into another multiple lines?

Tags: vim

For example, copy multiple lines A:

```
'fjalkfjljfllfs'
'dasldkjlasdjla'
'jlfajldjaflajl'
```

they are random string with same length.

I have multiple lines text B and want to insert A into B's same position (not begin or end):

```
'xxxx fjalkfjljfllfs xxxxx'
'xxxx dasldkjlasdjla xxxxx'
'xxxx jlfajldjaflajl xxxxx'
```

in vim, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mark you lines A via blockwise visual mode (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) and copy them with <kbd>y</kbd> you can just put them back with <kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: To enter blockwise visual mode, the default mapping is just ctrl+v